# How Do I Update My Intel Graphics Driver On Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, 15.04

I'm trying to update my intel graphics driver. But I can't find a download for Ubuntu 15.04. Please help me!

My processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5450

My graphics driver: Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2

Comment: There is an application "Additional Drivers" on Ubuntu that if an update is available it will tell you !

Comment: no it didn't tell me there was an update

Comment: So Sajid, how do you know there is an update?

Comment: my computer is old and I don't think I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

The graphic driver for your Intel Processor is a package called [xserver-xorg-video-intel](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel).
 The latest version available for 15.04 is 2:2.99.917-1~exp1ubuntu2.2, you can check the driver version on your system with the following commands in your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

> dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel

It will get updated if you do the normal upgrade regularly. You can also do the upgrade with the following commands:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

If you want to try the latest driver (which is not available in Ubuntu yet), you can download it from:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics